# JQueryUI Calling Open on dialog on working

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am loading some html using JQuery  .load and then using JQuery UI to open a dialog from a div in the loaded html. But it is not working and seems to be because the JQuery UI is not recognising the div exists although its loaded dynamically.

Do I have to do a .live or .on call somehow???

EDIT: Just realised divtimesheet is named twice so have changed one of them to divtimesheet_holder but still same problem?

```
   loadTimesheet = function () {
        var wkending =  getWeekEnding();
        var proId = $("#newtimesheet").attr("proid");
        $("#divtimesheet_holder").load("Timesheet/NewTimesheet", { proId: proId, enddate: "15/10/2014" }, function() { open();});
    }

   function open() {
        $("#clipboarddialog").dialog("open");
    }


<div id="clipboarddialog">
    <div id="clipboard">
        <div id="divtimesheet">
            @Html.Partial("Timesheet/TimesheetHeader", Model)
            @Html.Partial("Timesheet/TimesheetBody", Model)
            @Html.Partial("Timesheet/TimesheetFooter", Model)
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It should work because you're calling open() after loading the div. In `open()` before .dialog() do a `console.log($("#clipboarddialog"));`

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `$("#clipboarddialog").dialog({ options });` to initialize the widget.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#clipboarddialog").dialog({ 
        autoOpen: false
    });
});
```

Comment: I was doing that. But what worked was too add it before the Open statement. That is why I mentioned .live.

Comment: You don't need anything like that. The `#clipboarddialog` element isn't being added dynamically, only the contents of `#divtimesheet_holder` is.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways of opening the dialog in `jQuery`.

First, you can directly open the dialog without mentioning any `options` for `.dialog` method.

```
$("#clipboarddialog").dialog();
```

Second, you initialize the dialog and open the dialog anywhere

```
//set up options
$("#clipboarddialog").dialog({options});

//open
$("#clipboarddialog").dialog("open");
```

In your case, you should not provide any options to the .dialog

Simply call it this way

```
function open() {
    $("#clipboarddialog").dialog();
}
```

Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4yk89gxm/)

Hope this helps